# How to demo app flow in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I've been using Sketch, and have been asked to demo an app using Sketch. Currently, I've been designing the app in Android Studio, running the app on an emulator, taking screen shots, and dropping the screen shots into a Google Slide show, which is nice; however, boss wants something fancier, and asked me to look into how to use Sketch for demo. It's an opened question.

Basically, does Sketch have a feature for creating "App Flow" demos? Or if not, what is an effective way to present UIs in Sketch?

Maybe Sketch is not the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch offers the possibility to create a flow using Prototype: https://www.sketch.com/docs/prototyping/

After creating a flow, you can click on the "Preview" button on the top right of the UI and create a demo app.

You can do *basic* stuff but it probably lacks animation flow.
If you want to go further, there are quite a few Sketch plugins that can help you create animations. I'll link one here (Principle) just because I know it is used by many people, but it's obviously not the only one on the marker: https://principleformac.com/